# Read txt files via node,js;

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am building a Discord bot, mainly for moderation. So I have a set of bad words in a txt file, I want to write code for my node.js to read the words and delete them from the discord messages. I got the auto-deletion part covers, need help with the reading/detecting of the words in the text file part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Node.js' FileSystem (`fs`)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to read from files:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

let badwords;

try {
  badwords = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/badwords.txt', 'utf8')
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}

client.on('message', message => {
  badwords.forEach(badword => {
    if (badword == message.content) {
      message.delete()
      message.reply('You can not use that word here')
    }
  })
})
```